# Display GridView Edited row data in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my [screenshot-output](http://s21.postimg.org/y76k2lgl3/untitled.jpg)

When i click edit button, then then the edited row data need to display in the above text boxes(attached screenshot).

Here is the aspx file:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<center><div><h4>Student Details</h4></div></center>
    <table style="width: 100%;">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>

            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Textusername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Class"></asp:Label>

            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Textclass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Section"></asp:Label>

            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Textsection" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>       

    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
        </td>

        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Textaddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnsub" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsub_Click" OnClientClick="return register();" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnrst" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnrst_Click" />

        </td>
        <td>
        </td>

        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                SortExpression="Section" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="EditRow" HeaderText="Edit" 
                ShowHeader="True" Text="Edit" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" 
                ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="StoredProcedure2" 

        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Class" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Section" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Class" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Section" />
            </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Can anybody help me, how to achieve this one?

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Thanks.,

Comment: Do you use Update Panel ?

Comment: no.. i'm getting started.. I m new to asp...

Comment: While you are binding the data in gridview using bound field you also need to bind the ID as command argument on button. These ID on postback will let you get data from Datatable based on ID and then you can populate the respective text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the bind value in `Form` you need to set the `TextBox` value as `GridView` rows value within `RowCommandEvent`:

```
   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender,GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {      
         if(e.CommandName =="EditRow")
         {
           GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
           string id = gr.Cells[0].Text;
           txtname.Text =gr.Cells[1].Text;
           txtclass.Text=gr.Cells[2].Text;
           txtsection.Text =gr.Cells[3].Text;
           txtaddress.Text=gr.Cells[4].Text; 
         }
    }
```

GridView :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                SortExpression="Section" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
               <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnedit" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditRow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" 
                ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Or** Fetch the row as :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender,GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {      
             if(e.CommandName =="EditRow")
             {
                 int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);    
                 GridViewRow gr = GridView1.Rows[index];
                 string id = gr.Cells[0].Text;
               txtname.Text =gr.Cells[1].Text;
               txtclass.Text=gr.Cells[2].Text;
               txtsection.Text =gr.Cells[3].Text;
               txtaddress.Text=gr.Cells[4].Text; 
             }
        }
```

For more Reference :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `EditRow` is your Command Name that is Specified with your Button control   in Gridview `CommandName="EditRow" `  and `GridViewRow` represents an individual row in a GridView control. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What error? Make  `<asp:ButtonField>` to `<ItemTemplate><asp:Button /></ItemTemplate>`. See my updates.

Comment: This is generally occurs due to misspelled column names, should recheck that.  As you mention `DataKeyNames="Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4"` may havenot any columns with that names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93758/discussion-between-rani-and-rojalin-sahoo).

Answer (score 0):

First, add your GridView and Display Text boxes to Update Panel

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updt" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                 <center><div><h4>Student Details</h4></div></center>
        <table style="width: 100%;">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>

                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Textusername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Class"></asp:Label>

                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Textclass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Section"></asp:Label>

                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Textsection" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>       

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Textaddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnsub" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsub_Click" OnClientClick="return register();" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnrst" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnrst_Click" />

            </td>
            <td>
            </td>

            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
                 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                    SortExpression="Section" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                    SortExpression="Address" />
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="EditRow" HeaderText="Edit" 
                    ShowHeader="True" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" 
                    ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="StoredProcedure2" 

            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Class" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Section" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Class" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Section" />
                </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
         </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
                </Triggers>       
            </asp:UpdatePanel>   
</asp:Content>
```

This is how to get cell value of edit row on `RowCommandEvent`

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
            string _name = row.Cells[1].Text;                
            string _class = row.Cells[2].Text;                
            string _section = row.Cells[3].Text;                
            string _Address = row.Cells[4].Text;                
            //Add this value to your text box here //
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post all of your codes ? Including codes for `TextBox and Label` .